# BlackBerry "Handheld is resetting: Error: member changed name:" error while Debug as Blackberry Device

Tags: debugging, blackberry, handheld

"Handheld is resetting: Error: member changed name: com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.UserData.->email"

When I want to debug my app on BlackBerry 8520, I received this error popup on Eclipse. I also have test phones bb9700 and bb9900 but i dont get this error while debuging.

Any idea?